# Why this responsive CSS can't change my lay out?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="flexParent">
        <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar debug"></div>
        <div id="summary" class="mainContent debug"></div>  

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
@media (max-width:250px){
    .flexParent{display: flex;flex-direction:column;}
}
.debug{border-style: solid;}
.flexParent{display:flex;height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;flex-direction: row;}
.sidebar{flex: 0 1 200px;height: 100%;text-align: center;margin-right: 2px;}
.mainContent{flex: 1;}
```

When I try to set my browser to 240px, It doesn't work. I think this should change row to column.

Comment: Please provide JSFiddle or CodePen sample. Also add description of desired output.

Comment: media query need to be at the end

Comment: check at : https://jsfiddle.net/omasdezu/2/